# I use wamp for server use in php now i install phpstorm for working

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, wamp

so i install xamp but when i want to use it not work properry
  icant configure the mysql for my project

```
11:44:09 AM  [mysql]    Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
    11:44:09 AM  [mysql]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
    11:44:09 AM  [mysql]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
    11:44:09 AM  [mysql]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
    11:44:09 AM  [mysql]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
    11:44:09 AM  [mysql]    If you need more help, copy and post this
    11:44:09 AM  [mysql]    entire log window on the forums
```

Comment: Post your mysql_error.log

Comment: WAMP and XAMPP are basically the same thing. Both install an instance of Apache and MySQL. Uninstall which ever one you dont want to use anymore, after making backups of sites and databases. You error is because one version of MYSQL has captured port 3306 and the other cannot therefore gain access to it.